# Python-Stripe issuing card webhook that I will have to manually grant permission for payments to go through

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a Stripe issuing webhook that by default all issuing Stripe card payments are blocked, and will let me know when a cardholder is trying to make a payment with the issuing Stripe card.Then I would have to manually allow the card to approve the payment from the issuing card/cardholder to go through.I am failing to get this right.I could use some help thanks!

Here is the code:

```
    import stripe
    import json
    from flask import Flask

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
    def webhook(event):
        # Check if the event is an issuing event.
        if event['type'] != 'issuing.card.payment_attempted':
            return

       # Check if the payment is blocked by default.
        if event['data']['settings']['blocked']:
            # Get the user's email address.
            user_email = event['data']['customer']['email']

            # Send an email to the user asking them to approve the payment.
            send_email(user_email, 'Approve Payment', 'Your payment has been blocked. Please      approve it to complete your purchase.')

        # Otherwise, allow the payment to go through.
        else:
            # Update the payment to allow it to go through.
            stripe.issuing.PaymentAttempt.update(event['id'], blocked=False)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        webhook_secret = 'YOUR_WEBHOOK_SECRET'
        stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            request.data,
            request.headers['STRIPE_SIGNATURE'],
            webhook_secret
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are a few bugs in your code. First, you're not properly receiving the information sent to your webhook. Second, your code isn't correctly dealing with these incoming messages. I modified your webhook function.Try this:

```
webhook_secret = 'YOUR_WEBHOOK_SECRET'
payload = request.data.decode("utf-8")
sig_header = request.headers.get('Stripe-Signature')

try:
    event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(payload, sig_header, webhook_secret)
except (ValueError, stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError):
    return abort(400)

if event['type'] == 'issuing_transaction.created':
    transaction = event['data']['object']
    if transaction['authorized'] == False:
        user_email = "Get email here"
        send_email(user_email, 'Approve Payment', 'Your payment has been blocked. Please approve it to complete your purchase.')
return '', 200
```